# Problem in merging a gff file and a csv file in R

Tags: r, csv, bioinformatics, bioconductor, gff

I have a `gff` file and a `csv` file which looks like:

```
# CSV dataframe
file.csv <- read.table(text = "Sample  Name    Estimate    Std.Err P.Adjust
Sample_1    B005300.2.1 0.345930183 0.05662846  1.58E-06
Sample_1    B005230.2.1 0.048159129 0.013862871 0.019181546
Sample_1    B006450.2.1 -0.263951161    0.079297432 0.027327576
Sample_2    B005230.2.1 39.04308043 11.23861018 0.019181546
Sample_2    B006260.1.1 0.003968994 0.00063087  6.12E-07
Sample_2    B006170.2.1 0.117171563 0.024018888 0.000272761
Sample_3    B006450.2.1 0.012033053 0.003670908 0.030632664
Sample_3    B006980.1-c2.1  -0.007653796    0.002047582 0.009944649
Sample_3    B006980.1.1 -0.011369481    0.002871014 0.00539717", header = TRUE)

# GFF GRanges, example data
#dput(head(GFF))
GFF <- new("GRanges", seqnames = new("Rle", values = structure(1L, .Label = c("Bch01", "Bch02", "Bch03", "Bch04", "Bch05"), class = "factor"), lengths = 6L, 
    elementMetadata = NULL, metadata = list()), ranges = new("IRanges", 
    start = c(21882L, 21882L, 21882L, 21882L, 22697L, 22697L), 
    width = c(126L, 126L, 126L, 126L, 60L, 60L), NAMES = NULL, 
    elementType = "ANY", elementMetadata = NULL, metadata = list()), 
    strand = new("Rle", values = structure(2L, .Label = c("+", 
    "-", "*"), class = "factor"), lengths = 6L, elementMetadata = NULL, 
        metadata = list()), seqinfo = new("Seqinfo", seqnames = c("Bch01", "Bch02", "Bch03", "Bch04", "Bch05"), seqlengths = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), is_circular = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), genome = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), elementMetadata = new("DFrame", rownames = NULL, nrows = 6L, 
        listData = list(source = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L), .Label = "maker", class = "factor"), type = structure(c(1L, 
        2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("CDS", "exon", "gene", 
        "mRNA", "three_prime_UTR", "five_prime_UTR"), class = "factor"), 
            score = c(NA, NA, NA, 126, NA, NA), phase = c(0L, 
            NA, NA, NA, 0L, NA), ID = c("B024400.1.1:cds", 
            "B024400.1.1:exon:2", "B024400.1", 
            "B024400.1.1", "B008910.1.1:cds", 
            "B008910.1.1:exon:4"), Parent = new("CompressedCharacterList", 
                elementType = "character", elementMetadata = NULL, 
                metadata = list(), unlistData = c("B024400.1.1", 
                "B024400.1.1", "B024400.1", 
                "B008910.1.1", "B008910.1.1"
                ), partitioning = new("PartitioningByEnd", end = c(1L, 
                2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), NAMES = NULL, elementType = "ANY", 
                  elementMetadata = NULL, metadata = list())), 
            Name = c(NA, NA, "B024400.1", "B024400.1.1", 
            NA, NA), Note = new("CompressedCharacterList", elementType = "character", 
                elementMetadata = NULL, metadata = list(), unlistData = c("Similar to B024400.1.1: LOW QUALITY:50S ribosomal protein L4, chloroplastic", "Similar to B024400.1.1: LOW QUALITY:50S ribosomal protein L4, chloroplastic"), partitioning = new("PartitioningByEnd", end = c(0L, 
                0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), NAMES = NULL, elementType = "ANY", 
                  elementMetadata = NULL, metadata = list())), 
            ref_id = c(NA, NA, "B024400.1.1", "B024400.1.1", 
            NA, NA), Dbxref = new("CompressedCharacterList", 
                elementType = "character", elementMetadata = NULL, 
                metadata = list(), unlistData = character(0), 
                partitioning = new("PartitioningByEnd", end = c(0L, 
                0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), NAMES = NULL, elementType = "ANY", 
                  elementMetadata = NULL, metadata = list())), 
            Ontology_term = new("CompressedCharacterList", elementType = "character", 
                elementMetadata = NULL, metadata = list(), unlistData = character(0), 
                partitioning = new("PartitioningByEnd", end = c(0L, 
                0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), NAMES = NULL, elementType = "ANY", 
                  elementMetadata = NULL, metadata = list()))), 
        elementType = "ANY", elementMetadata = NULL, metadata = list()), 
    elementType = "ANY", metadata = list())
```

I want to merge both the files by column `Name`. I tried:

```
GFF = rtracklayer::import("gene_models.gff")
merge_data<-merge(file.csv,GFF,by="Name")
```

But in the csv file, I have same `Name` values for different `Samples` such as `B005230.2.1` for both `Sample1` and `Sample2` whereas it only occurs in `GFF` file once. Because of this, the merge file is messed up. I will appreciate any help to fix this problem. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "messed up"? In this case it is one-to-many merge, it is expected that "Name" would match to multiple samples.

Comment: Can you share an example gff file: `dput(head(GFF))`.

Comment: @zx8754, I have added this information in the question. By messed up I mean it starts with a random 'Name' value for any 'Sample' without any order. So, I am not being able to make complete sense of the merge file. Yes, in this case, ideally one value from GFF file should merge to many same values in csv files.

Comment: With your example CSV and GFF, there is no match on "Name", I tried to add some matching names to CSV, merge worked fine. Still not clear what the problem is.

Comment: When I import the GFF file, there is a column  'Name' with same names as csv file column 'Name'.

Comment: Yes, I understand, I used your GFF example and merged on "Name" column.

Comment: So, the problem is it outputs the results based on chromosome numbers starting from chromosome1. I want to output the results in a similar way as the input i.e., based on sample order.

Comment: I see, then add a rownumber to CSV, as `file.csv$rn <- seq(nrow(file.csv))`, then merge, then reorder the result `merge_data <- merge_data[ order(merge_data$rn), ]`

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Comment: Glad, it worked for you. Closing this post as duplicate of "merge keep order" post, see linked post for more options.